# How to use SoapUI QUERY MATCH?

Tags: xml, xpath, soap, match, soapui

I have the following request that is sent to my MockService in SoapUI:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <S:Body>
    <my-message>
      <message-content>
        <ping-message/>                                                                                                                                           
      </message-content>
    </my-message>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

and I want to select the response based on the existance of the tag .

Therefore I use the XPath expression `//message-content/ping-message`
and the expected value `<ping-message>`.

But SoapUI just gives me the error `ERROR:com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: Failed to find MockResponse` which is in no way helpful.

How can I find out what exactly is going wrong? What is actually the problem in this configuration? Is the XPath wrong? Is the expected value wrong?

Comment: I know it is late. Are you still having the problem? If so, would you mind showing the screen shot of MockService?